# JAVA - Making Constructors, Calling Sets, and Replacing Chars in a String using set Classes

Tags: java, string, char

In Java, where should I aim (I enjoy figuring it out myself) to get, with sample data:
I am Sam I am a

the output:
I am Sam I am - letter to remove a
I m Sm I m

Basically, it is to "Remove all instances of the specified removal letter from the original sentence"

As this is for a class, I am limited with what I can do. For this assignment I am stuck with the given classes/constructors and am not allowed to make any more unless it is noted, which in my case, is to create another constructor class; Anyway, that has been the real challenge as it is hard to get help (No matter how many times I've googled!) with it being so specific and I new to the language. 
Here is what I was given:

```js
 
import static java.lang.System.*;
 
public class LetterRemover
{
   private String sentence;
   private char lookFor;
 
    public LetterRemover()
    {
        //call set
    }
 
    //add in second constructor
     
     
    public void setRemover(String s, char rem)
    {
        sentence = s;
        lookFor = rem;
    }
 
    public String removeLetters()
    {
        String cleaned=sentence;
        return cleaned;
    }
 
    public String toString()
    {
        return sentence + " - letter to remove " + lookFor;
    }
}
```

This is what I've done so far:

```js
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class LetterRemover
{
   private String sentence;
   private String lookFor;

 public LetterRemover()
 {
     //I am not sure what this means
  
 }

 //add in second constructor
 
 
 public void setRemover(String s, String rem)
 {
  sentence = s;
  lookFor = rem;
 }

 public String removeLetters()
 {
  sentence = sentence.replaceAll(lookFor,"");
     String cleaned=sentence;
  return cleaned;
 }

 public String toString()
 {
  return sentence + " - letter to remove " + lookFor;
  
  
 }
}
```

I tried changing the char to a string for the "lookfor" to use the replace all method which seemed after a lot of research and the best way to get the letters out.
Is there any noticeable mistakes and where should I look to fix them? I do not really want the right code, or for anyone to "do" the work for me. I really want to try and figure it out. But I need a little help in pointing in the right direction to get my desired output :)
Let me know if there is any other details or whatnot, this is also , this is also my first time using the site. There were many similar questions to this, but as I really am a beginner I struggled to understand people's explanations

--Edit--

Moving to my runner class, this is what I wrote, trying to get for the desired output. I am not really sure how to deal with output as I really have just started learning to write them myself.
I keep getting a void error though:

```js
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class LetterRemoverRunner
{
 public static void main( String args[] )
 {
  LetterRemover test = new LetterRemover
    (test.setRemover("I really want dumplings","l"));
           
 }
}
```

Comment: You can also post the output that you are getting now. This will help us to understand the problem exactly.

Comment: Yes, ok! Will add in a sec.

Comment: @NivethaT hopefully this helps you all to understand, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code and confirm this is what your requirement is.

***LetterRemoverRunner.java***

```
public class LetterRemoverRunner {
public static void main(String args[])
{
    LetterRemover test = new LetterRemover ();
    test.setRemover("I really want dumplings","l");
    System.out.println(test.toString());
    System.out.println("Removed :"+test.removeLetters());
 }
}
```

**LetterRemover.java**

```
public class LetterRemover
{
 private String sentence;
 private String lookFor;

public LetterRemover()
{
    //I am not sure what this means

}

public void setRemover(String s, String rem)
{
    this.sentence = s;
    this.lookFor = rem;
}

public String removeLetters()
{
    sentence = sentence.replaceAll(lookFor,"");
    String cleaned=sentence;
    return cleaned;
}

public String toString()
{
    return sentence + " - letter to remove " + lookFor;     

}
```

}

Comment: The question specifically said he didn't want an answer posted as he wanted to figure it out himself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pleased you suggested you don't want the answer - much better way to learn!

I'm not sure you've understood constructors yet. You're line:

```
LetterRemover test = new LetterRemover
   (test.setRemover("I really want dumplings","l"));
```

Is going to give you a null pointer error because it's calling `setRemover` on `test` before `test` has been constructed. You should be constructing the object with its `sentence` and `lookFor` values before calling setRemover.

Here are some things you might want to look at:

1. The `String.indexOf` method will look for a certain character or string and tell you where to find it (or if it isn't in the string at all).
2. The `String.substring` method allows you to take part of a string using string positions
3. You can build a new string by concatenating substrings together
4. Using a `while` loop you can continue using indexOf until the target cannot be found.

As you've pointed out, you can also use one of the `replace` methods to replace the target with "".

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I was given the link to the Overview of the Java Platform, but there was so much it was overwhelming! I'll try looking into other methods besides replace, the ones suggested.